# Character submitted wrong after replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, greasemonkey, blur

i use a greasemonkey script to replace any commas or semicolons from fields. 
There are several internal websites where i have to do this, some only with input fields, some with textarea.

The script actually works, but when i submit the form, the replaced characters of the textareas will still get submitted as commas and semicolons.

To be sure that the submit will not be triggered before last blur, i added a alert.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function(){
$("textarea").blur(function(){
    this.value=this.value.replace(/[,;]/g, "-");
    this.value=this.value.replace(/\n/g, " ");
});
$("input").blur(function(){
   this.value=this.value.replace(/[,;]/g, "-");
   this.value=this.value.replace(/\n/g, " ");
});
});

var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
if (window.location.href == "<website-url>")
nodes[39].setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("Data validated")');
    else
nodes[0].setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("Data validated")');
```

Any ideas? Tested with different browsers and different characters.

Comment: I'd suggest doing the update in the `submit` event of the form, rather than (or in addition to) the `blur` event on the fields; it wouldn't surprise me at all if `blur` fired after `submit` for the field you were in just prior to submitting.

Comment: `alert` is just about the worst possible way to try to do that. :-) `alert` and `focus`/`blur` have extremely strange interplay, and it varies from browser to browser.

Comment: Yea, the alert part was actually to provide a time frame between the click and the actually submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the `submit` event to make sure any lingering changes not handled yet by `blur` are handled before submission:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updateValue() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[,;]/g, "-").replace(/\n/g, " ");
    }
    $("textarea, input").blur(updateValue);
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $(this).find("textarea, input").each(updateValue);
    });
});
```

Sadly, Stack Snippets don't allow forms, so here's the above [live on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rj0pkyj/). Note that if you type, say, `cute;kittens` into the field and then either tab out of it or submit it, it's changed to `cute-kittens` and that's the value that gets submitted to Google if you send the form.

Comment: actually i didnt check correct, this has the same issues as before. the characters are only getting visually replaced

Comment: @PixPaw: This absolute *does* work, when the user leaves the field and then also on form submit. As I said before, you don't want to replace the value of a field while the user is typing in it (at least not without doing a **lot** more work than in Konstantin's answer to avoid constantly screwing up the user's insert location). What do you mean by "only visually"? It definitely changes the value of the field.

Comment: @PixPaw: I've added a jsFiddle demonstrating it working.

Comment: ok, i was able to troubleshoot the problem. I had to add " and ' to the replaceable characters aswell, which **does** work with your snippet. When i do the same on the website with that textarea and place a ' it gets replaced (which i can see when i blur it), however, if i submit, the ' gets submitted and causes issues and cut off everything after the '

I noticed this behaviour only on textarea input, everything works good on single line forms.

Comment: @PixPaw: Works just fine if I add `'` and `"` and use a `textarea` and type in `cute'kittens` and click Search: https://jsfiddle.net/1rj0pkyj/1/ What gets submitted is the **updated** value, `cute-kittens`.

Comment: Yes i see and agree it works on the fiddle, so must be something on that internal website which i cant explain myself. Even stranger that this does not cause issues when using the type while input solution...

Does it makes sense to approach if from another angle and maybe parse the complete submitted string and replace it from there?

Comment: @PixPaw: I'm afraid I couldn't say, it'll depend too much on your environment.

Comment: Ill go ahead and use both of your solutions to have the highest workability while having less annoyance with the moving cursor